# UIImageView size suddenly change after set new image

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a problem that I can't find the errors as titled. And I have searched so many times that similar or related questions, that can't solve.

I am building an App that can change the Image of A `UIImageView` with a button. everything is fine until I use another button to change the size of imageView (with `UIView animateWithDuration + CGAffineTransformMakeRotation`), then use that button for changing image.

strange output with no errors happen! the imageview size change back and the position move to other places.

Sorry about my poor english.

with graphics,

1. I have this view [no size changed view][1]
2. I use `animateWithDuration + CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` change the size & orientations, to make the view fullscreen like this [size changed view][2]
3. Then I change this image of this view by `imageView.image = newImage(UIImage)`
4. However, the view change to this [strange view][3] either the size or position are changed!

But, there's nothing if I change the image at Step 1 (no orientation & set frame)

Please help, I can't find the errors because there only one place that change the size&orientation of the view.

I wonder there is something `UIImage` would affect the `UIImageView`. But I can't find the answer.

(the photos are down below)

this is the code to rotate the image ivew
if there is already set image, after rotation, the image is also fine
But problem get after rotation, and then set the new image to the image view

```
-(void)transformToDirection:(NSInteger)dir
{
rotation = M_PI_2;
CGFloat screenW = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
CGFloat screenH = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
CGRect portraitFrame = _imageVIew.frame;
CGRect landscapeFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenW, screenH);

    switch (dir) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
                _imageVIew.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3/4 * rotation);
                [_imageVIew setFrame:portraitFrame];
            }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                isFullScreen = false;
            }];
        }
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
                _imageVIew.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);
                [_imageVIew setFrame:landscapeFrame];

            }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                isFullScreen = true;
            }];
        }
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:TIME_ANIMATE_FULLSCREEN delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
                _imageVIew.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-rotation);
                [_imageVIew setFrame:landscapeFrame];
            }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                isFullScreen = true;
            }];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

this is the image view set image (all new images are the same size), which is called by a button.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (loadedimage) {
            self.imageVIew.image = loadedimage;
        } else {
            self.PBMainImageVIew.image = nil;
            dlog(@"request image failed");
        }
    });
```

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQvTf.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH3cn.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8yBA.png

Comment: Hello, do these 2 pictures (image 1 and new image) have the same size ratio?

Comment: yes, they have the same size ratio, @BashirSidani

Comment: so you are rotating the image 90 degrees and making it as big as the screen right? also you want the new image rotated right?

Comment: yes for the your 1st question, but I set the new image to the rotated image view, I don't rotate the image but the view only
2nd question yes, I want the newly image also rotated in the same imageview

@BashirSidani

Comment: okay, when you set the new image, try to use animateWithDuration + CGAffineTransformMakeRotation again like you used it the firs time. if you se aanimation time set it to 0 and tell me the results

Comment: @BashirSidani I tried the same animation right below the set image, but nothing change, It still appear with strange view like the link 3.

More for details, the size of the view is changed based on the orientation of the Device, When I put it faceUp and then landscape mode, The image go to the right location with right size.

however the strange happen When I set new image, it flashes to a unknow position

Comment: after the animation, try to this the imageview.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)

Comment: @BashirSidani so sad, nothing change at all. but still thanks for helping.

Comment: the frame does not change?

Comment: @BashirSidani yes, I log the frame with width / height & locations

Comment: can you please post your code and I will be happy to fix it :), just the code related to this image

Comment: @BashirSidani sorry for late replying, I still can't solve it, thank you